# stable symbol's this pointer is NULL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static, release

environment :
visual studio 2008 sp1(c++)
windows 7 sp1 x64
win32 api + directx game project

problem :

```
//superclass of every variables.
//METHOD has automatically type-cast to int, float, string.
//and array function.
//this class series is using from script interpreter system.
class METHOD {  // it is superclass of everything
friend class INTERPRETER;


protected:
BOOL constant;
//for variables & Functions
//TCHAR* m_name;
std::wstring m_name;

KEYWORD m_key;
RESERVED m_res;

int int_result;
std::wstring str_result;
float float_result;
TYPE m_type;

int m_level;

//tree
METHOD* root_ofme;
METHOD* sibling;
METHOD* left;
METHOD* right;
METHOD* parent;


//for FOR & BREAK class
//METHOD* m_targetToBreak;
BOOL m_breakingNow;

int m_rank; //priority

private:

public:
//constant
void EnableConstant(BOOL bcon);
void EnableConstant();
BOOL isConst();
//setter event
std::vector<METHOD*>* m_triggerTable;
std::vector<std::vector<METHOD*>*>* m_triggerArgs;

virtual void RunTrigger();
virtual void setTrigger(METHOD* mt, std::vector<METHOD*>* pVecArg);
virtual void removeTrigger(METHOD* mt);

//mapset
VMAP& GetVMap() const;
VMAP::iterator& MyMapItr() const;
BOOL HasVMap() const;
int GetArraySize() const;
private:
VMAP* m_map;
VMAP::iterator* m_my_itr;
public:
VARIABLE* m_zero;
virtual BOOL isZeroExternal();
BOOL m_ExternalZero;
int GetMethodIndex();
METHOD* GetSearchArray(int range);


METHOD* m_myParentFunc;
virtual METHOD* getParentFunc();

METHOD* m_OverParams;
virtual BOOL isOverflowParam();
BOOL m_bIsOverflowParam;

virtual METHOD* getOverParam();

METHOD* v;  //node pointer : using it to pointing other METHOD class


virtual KEYWORD getMyOwnKey();
virtual RESERVED getMyOwnRes();
virtual METHOD* getMyOwnRight();
virtual METHOD* getMyOwnLeft();
virtual METHOD* getMyOwnParent();

virtual METHOD* getParentArray();
METHOD* m_mtBodyTrue;


//For Operations
virtual int getOperationRank();

//Label & goto
virtual void setValid();
//virtual BOOL getVaild();
virtual BOOL getValid();
virtual size_t getTargetToJump();
virtual void setTargetToJump(size_t setvalue);

virtual KEYWORD getKey();
virtual RESERVED getRes();

//virtual void Operation();

//for brace
virtual void SetOpenner();
virtual void SetCloser();
virtual BOOL IsOpenner();
virtual void SetCounter(size_t);
virtual size_t GetCounter();

//for Callfunc
virtual void setFunc(METHOD* func);
virtual METHOD* getFunc();
virtual void push_back_arg(METHOD* mt);

//For Reserved, Functions & Variables
//variables
virtual void Run_PostOrder();
virtual void Run_InOrder();
virtual void Operation(std::vector<METHOD*>* arg_arglist);
virtual void Operation();

//virtual void FuncOperation(METHOD* pf, void* arg_arglist=NULL);
virtual int getsize();
virtual int getsize(int arraynum);

//for Array Support Version virtuals
virtual METHOD* getArray(int arraynum);
virtual METHOD* searchArray(int arraynum);
virtual void clearArray();
virtual void CopyTotalArrayTo(METHOD* varDest) const;
virtual void CopyTotalArrayFrom(const METHOD* varSrc);
private:
static void CopyArray(VMAP* destMap, const VMAP* srcMap);
public:
virtual size_t getNumArray();

//get//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
virtual int getInt() const;
virtual std::wstring getStr() const;
virtual float getFloat() const;
virtual int getINT();
virtual std::wstring getSTR();
virtual float getFLOAT();
virtual METHOD* getMethod() const;
//7 get

virtual int getInt(int arraynum);
virtual std::wstring getStr(int arraynum);
virtual float getFloat(int arraynum);
virtual int getINT(int arraynum);
virtual std::wstring getSTR(int arraynum);
virtual float getFLOAT(int arraynum);
virtual METHOD* getMethod(int arraynum);
//7 array-get
//14 gets
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//type//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
virtual TYPE type() const;
virtual TYPE typeCast(TYPE totype);
//2 type

virtual TYPE type(int arraynum);
virtual TYPE typeCast(int arraynum, TYPE totype);
//2 array-type
//4 types
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//set//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//non-array set
virtual void set(const METHOD* var);
virtual void set(const int k);
virtual void set(TCHAR* start, TCHAR* end);
virtual void set(std::wstring& start, int size);
virtual void set(const std::wstring& target);
virtual void set(const float f);
//6 set
virtual void set(int arraynum, const METHOD* var);
virtual void set(int arraynum, const int k);
virtual void set(int arraynum, TCHAR* start, TCHAR* end);
virtual void set(int arraynum, std::wstring& start, int size);
virtual void set(int arraynum, const std::wstring& target);
virtual void set(int arraynum, const float f);
//6 array-set
//12 sets

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//for Variable & Functions
//virtual void setName(TCHAR* name, size_t size);   //삭제됨
virtual void setName(TCHAR* name);
virtual void setName(WORDCLIPPER* wc);
virtual void setName(const std::wstring& name);
virtual const std::wstring& getName() const;
virtual int getArgnum();
virtual int getNumParam();
virtual TYPE getArgTYPE(int i);

//for FOR & BREAK class
virtual BOOL isFOR();
virtual void Break();
virtual void Enter();
virtual void Leave();
virtual BOOL State();


//FOR TREES
//root setting
virtual void RootSet(METHOD* mt);
virtual METHOD* RootGet();
virtual void SetParent(METHOD* mt);
virtual void SetLeft(METHOD* mt);
virtual void SetRight(METHOD* mt);
virtual METHOD* GetParent();
virtual METHOD* getLeft();
virtual METHOD* getRight();

//for everythings
virtual int getLevel();
virtual int setLevel(int lv);
METHOD();
~METHOD();
METHOD(const METHOD&);

//addinational basic ctor
METHOD(const std::wstring& name, const std::wstring& strVal);
METHOD(const std::wstring& name, const int intVal);
METHOD(const std::wstring& name, const float floatVal);
//111213
METHOD(const std::wstring& strVal);
METHOD(const int intVal);
METHOD(const float floatVal);
//111213
METHOD operator + (const METHOD& addend) const;
METHOD operator - (const METHOD& addend) const;
METHOD operator * (const METHOD& divisor) const;
METHOD operator / (const METHOD& divisor) const;
METHOD operator % (const METHOD& divisor) const;
METHOD& operator += (const METHOD& addend);
METHOD& operator -= (const METHOD& addend);
METHOD& operator *= (const METHOD& divisor);
METHOD& operator /= (const METHOD& divisor);
METHOD& operator %= (const METHOD& divisor);
BOOL operator == (const METHOD& comptarget) const;
BOOL operator != (const METHOD& comptarget) const;
operator unsigned int() const;
operator int() const;
operator float() const;
operator std::wstring() const;
operator bool() const;
operator unsigned long() const;
operator long() const;

private:
//111213 compare
static BOOL compare_totalArray(const METHOD* first, const METHOD* second, BOOL ignoreCase_string_compare,BOOL ignore_type_difference);
static BOOL compare_single(const METHOD* first, const METHOD* second, BOOL ignoreCase_string_compare,BOOL ignore_type_difference);

void CopySingleMethodFrom_NotCast(const METHOD* from);

//only called once
void First_Initializer();

};




//this is POWER operator class.
class POWER : public METHOD {
public:
virtual void Operation();  //doing POW operation using left-child node(METHOD*) and right-child node(METHOD*). the result is saved to this class's result.
const static KEYWORD key = Key_Caret;
POWER();
~POWER();
};


//and using it in static function

//making terrain function. it decide terrain's size using parameter 2^szTile+1, 2^TileNum, 2^TilePackNum
HRESULT SETTERRAINTOTAL::SetTerrainTotal( int szTile, int TileNum, int TilePackNum, size_t Scene /*= -1*/, int resource_id /*= -1*/ )
{
#define RATION_MODE
#ifdef RATION_MODE  

if(Scene == -1) Scene = vgp->GetCurrentSceneNumber();
VLogicPackage* vl = vgp->GetScene(Scene);
if(!vl) return E_FAIL;

POWER RatioTileSize; //A
RatioTileSize.SetLeft(&VARIABLE(2));
RatioTileSize.SetRight(&VARIABLE(szTile));
RatioTileSize.Operation();

POWER RatioNumTile; //B
RatioNumTile.SetLeft(&VARIABLE(2));
RatioNumTile.SetRight(&VARIABLE(TileNum));
RatioNumTile.Operation();

POWER RatioTilePack; //C
RatioTilePack.SetLeft(&VARIABLE(2));
RatioTilePack.SetRight(&VARIABLE(TilePackNum));
RatioTilePack.Operation();

if(FAILED(vl->SetTerrainTotal(
    RatioTileSize+VARIABLE(1),
    RatioNumTile,
    RatioTilePack,
    resource_id)))
    return E_FAIL;
#else
if(FAILED(vl->SetTerrainTotal(
    TileSize,
    NumTile     ,
    NumTilePack ,
    resource_id)))
    return E_FAIL;
#endif
return S_OK;
}
```

the problem occurs point A,B,C only Release mode.
when i trace using debugger on release mode, in the A,B,C point's METHOD() function, after calling of void First_Initializer(), the 'this' pointer of each POWER class is 0x00000000 (NULL). i cant confident because release mode, but it actually occurs problem. (And the 'debug mode' is no problem)
when creator ends and continue step-by-step visual studio debugger, the POWER class's stack instance's virtual function table is NULL

i digged it, and know somthings : this problem only occurs with 'in static function' and 'stack symbol(no heap symbol for example, using new...)'.
but i don't know why this problem occuring exactly.

And i apologize to you my terrible english and long-long source code. (but i'd try my best... i tried the source code make shorter...)

Comment: You don't include the source of the constructors of METHOD or POWER.

Comment: I suggest you read http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's not as stable as you thought. ;)

Heap corruption?  Try dynamic checkers like `valgrind`, Electric Fence, or `Purify` to spot the problem.  In the absence of those, use your debugger to catch the protection/segmentation fault in the act.  If the failure is easily reproduced and occurs with the same circumstances, you should be able to bisect the problem domain, working backwards from the fault.

---

As a totally unsolicited comment -- naming things is extremely important (and often underrated) and overloading the term `METHOD` as an actual class is a total mindblower.  If you wanted extremely dynamic programming, C++ might not be the right solution.  Also, having a class with a high count of methods or members sometimes suggests that perhaps it could be better decomposed.